# Java Supplier<> get origins information

Tags: java, supplier

I Use the Supplier in my code to call restTemplate and make the custom Message when have exception..

But, im my message, i need get information by my requestCall, But when i cast the request the java thow error

---

...

My code:

> ```
> public void execute() {
>     HttpHeaders headers = buildDefaultHeaders();
>     UriBuilder uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(wdd3dGatewayEndpoint + API_URL);
>     HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);
>     this.executeRequest(() -> restTemplate.exchange(uri.build(), HttpMethod.DELETE, request, Void.class));
> }
> ```

My Supplier

> ```
> protected ResponseEntity executeRequest(Supplier<ResponseEntity> request) {
>     try {
>         ResponseEntity response = request.get();
>         updateSessionToken(response);
>         return response;
>     } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
>         String msg = "WDD3D-Error in service communication<br>" + e.getResponseBodyAsString();
>         throw new MaestroException(msg);
>     }
> }
> ```

Now, i try cast to get URL...

> ```
> protected ResponseEntity executeRequest(Supplier<ResponseEntity> request) {
>     try {
>         ResponseEntity response = request.get();
>         updateSessionToken(response);
>         return response;
>     } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
>
>         //THROW EXEPTION HERE... PLEASE HELP...
>         RequestEntity requestEntity = (RequestEntity) request;
>         
>         String url = requestEntity.getUrl().toString();
>         String msg = "WDD3D-Error in service communication<br>" + e.getResponseBodyAsString();
>         throw new MaestroException(msg);
>     }
> }]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `get()` method of the `Supplier`, see more in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     RequestEntity requestEntity = (RequestEntity) request;
> ```

You are trying to cast a `Supplier<ResponseEntity>` to a `RequestEntity`.
These are two very different classes and such a cast will never work.

Maybe you want to call `request.get()` and get the URL from the `ResponseEntity` that you have.

Tell me if it works for you in the comments or we need to debug further ?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you are trying to get from the `RequestEntity` is the URL, which you can't get from the `Supplier<ResponseEntity>` since it is not a `RequestEntity`, so why not just pass the URL as another parameter to `executeRequest`? Then it would have the additional information it needs to log the error.